# Calculate previous week data in Teradata

Tags: teradata, weekday

How to calculate prior 7 days data (Sunday-Saturday of the previous week). on whatever day of week it is run it should always give Sunday-Saturday of the previous week.
thanks

Comment: Please, can you improve the question, that data exactly do you need? Data (tables and databases) which  changed last week or what?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another fine use for the calendar table:

```
select calendar_date
from
sys_calendar.calendar
where
week_of_calendar =
(select week_of_calendar from sys_calendar.calendar where calendar_date = current_Date) -1
```

Answer (score 7):

What's your Teradata release?

TD14 supports `NEXT_DAY`, which returns the first "weekday" later than the date specified:

```
SELECT NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'sun'),    -- next sunday
       NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'sun')-14, -- previous week's sunday
       NEXT_DAY(CURRENT_DATE, 'sun')-8   -- previous week's saturday
```

Edit:

In TD13 you can subtract the day of week to get the previous week's end date, e.g. `(CURRENT_DATE - DATE '0001-01-01') MOD 7 + 1` returns 1 to 7 for Monday to Sunday based on the known Monday '0001-01-01'.

Modified to your needs (week starts on Sunday) this results in:

```
SELECT
   CURRENT_DATE - ((CURRENT_DATE - DATE '0001-01-07') MOD 7 + 7),  -- previous week's Sunday 
   CURRENT_DATE - ((CURRENT_DATE - DATE '0001-01-07') MOD 7 + 1)   -- previous week's Saturday
```

Comment: Very cool, didn't know about that function.  BTW, I think you mean -7 for your previous saturday, not 8.

Comment: Or, it could just be that I'm incapable of reading sometimes, and didn't catch that you were passing in Sunday for the parameter.

Comment: @user3438498: TD13 is an ancient version :-) I added a solution for 13, too.